# How to get multi class confidence score from fine tuned bert model?

Tags: nlp, classification, bert-language-model

I have used pretrained bert model for intent classification(uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12). The model showing the output as a predicted intent. Below is the code of how i am getting prediction:

```py
sentences = ["i want to open a bank account"]
pred_tokens = map(tokenizer.tokenize, sentences)
pred_tokens = map(lambda tok: ["[CLS]"] + tok + ["[SEP]"], pred_tokens)
pred_token_ids = list(map(tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids, pred_tokens))
pred_token_ids = map(
    lambda tids: tids +[0]*(data.max_seq_len-len(tids)),
    pred_token_ids)
pred_token_ids = np.array(list(pred_token_ids))
predictions = model.predict(pred_token_ids).argmax(axis=-1)
for text, label in zip(sentences, predictions):
    print("text:", text, "\nintent:", classes[label])
    print()
```

The output is:

```
text: I want to open a bank account
intent: open_account
```

Now I want to get the confidence score of the text intent, for example:

```
intent: open_account
confidence score: 98.30
```

Answer (score 4):

Calling `model.predict(pred_token_ids)` returns so-called logits, i.e., unnormalized probability distribution over the target classes. You can normalize it by doing a [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) over the logits, i.e., `F.softmax(logits, axis=-1)` (see [PyTorch [documentation for more details](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.softmax.html)).

You can then get the confidence simply by getting the probability corresponding to the prediction.

Answer (score -1):

i have solved the problem. i have write a function to find the confidence of each class:

```
new_pred = model.predict(pred_token_ids)

def get_final_output(pred, classes):
    predictions = pred[0]

    classes = np.array(classes)
    ids = np.argsort(-predictions)
    classes = classes[ids]
    predictions = -np.sort(-predictions)

    for i in range(pred.shape[1]):
        print("%s has confidence = %s" % (classes[i], (predictions[i]*100)))
```

now call the function, here classes is the list of unique class name we want to predict.

```
#classes = train.intent.unique().tolist()

get_final_output(new_pred,classes)
```

the output will be confidence score of each class.